# Visual Studio 2019 NOT working with INTEL Parallel Studio XE 2019

Tags: fortran, ide

I am on Windows 10, and I can't seem to get my 2019VS to see the Fortran So I can create a Fortran Project. I have Update 8 for INTEL Parallel Studio XE 2019.. There is no INTEL(R) Fortran template that comes up. ONLY the other languages(F#,C++,python,......etc) How can I get the 2019 Visual studio to recognize I have a Parallel Studio 2019 version of Fortran ??

Comment: Please check your stated update number for Intel Parallel Studio.

Comment: Please check in VS IDE --> Help --> About Microsoft Visual Studio, if a line with Intel Visual Fortran Compiler is available. If not then deinstall and reinstall the Intel Parallel Studio. Please be aware that you can select the VS integration during the setup of Intel Parallel Studio. Just check if VS 2019 has been correctly selected.

Comment: In case that Visual Fortran Compiler is present in the About box of VS, then you can create a new Fortran project by selecting `Fortran` in the Drop-down list between `Recent project templates` and `All platforms`.